# Out of curiosity, who is the stack exchange user with the most combined questions?

Tags: discussion

Who is the Stack Exchange User with the most total questions among all Stack Exchange sub-websites?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the time I'm writing this... that's [Tim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141196/tim) with 4175 questions network-wide including meta sites. In second place is [Franck Dernoncourt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178179/franck-dernoncourt) with 2815 questions. And rounding out the top 3 we have [B. Clay Shannon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/196819/b-clay-shannon) with 2618.

This includes child metas. Deleted questions are not counted.